# Magento 2: Hide success message after 5 seconds in mobile screen

Tags: magento2

How to hide success messages after 5 seconds in Magento 2? I want to hide this message shown in the below picture after 5 seconds. it is coming from message.phtml file.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Create app/code/Rakesh/MagentoStackExchange/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages': {
                'Rakesh_MagentoStackExchange/js/view/messages-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> 2. Create app/code/Rakesh/MagentoStackExchange/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages-mixin.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            /**
             * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                var self = this;
                self.messages.subscribe(function(messages) {
                    if (messages.messages) {
                        if (messages.messages.length > 0) {
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                customerData.set('messages', {});
                            }, 3000);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Clear browser js cache.

Comment: yes its working but i just want to run setTimout function only on mobile screen. screen with less than 800. how can i modify it?

Comment: @JunaidAshfaq may be you need to add this condition `if(screen.width < 800) {
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    customerData.set('messages', {});
                                }, 5000); //disappear the message in 5 seconds
                            }`

Comment: yes its working i have added (screen.width < 800) in condition thanks

Comment: how do you clear browser cache

Comment: Do i need <sequence> <module name="Magento_Theme"/> </sequence> in module.xml

Comment: self.messages.subscribe does this mean it only works for newsletter subscription?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by overriding the Magento's `messages-mixin.js` in your custom module.

> view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/view/messages-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> view/frontend/web/js/view/messages-mixin.js

```
define([
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (customerData) {
    'use strict';    
    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            initialize: function () {
                this._super();
                var self = this;
                self.messages.subscribe(function(messages) {
                    if (messages.messages) {
                        if (messages.messages.length > 0) {
                            if (window.screen.width < 800) {
                                setTimeout(function() {
                                    customerData.set('messages', {});
                                }, 5000); //disappear the message in 5 seconds
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Run the below commands after the changes:

```
php bin/magento c:f
```

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: yes its working but i just want to run setTimout function only on mobile screen. screen with less than 800. how can i modify it?

Comment: Updated my answer, please check.

Comment: yes its working i have added (screen.width < 800) in condition thanks

Comment: Hi @Sumit this is not working for me I created a new module and i followed your steps but not working

Comment: Do i need <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Theme"/>
        </sequence> in module.xml

Comment: self.messages.subscribe does this mean it only works for newsletter subscription?